# setTimeout dont works?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

My JavaScript code is this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        ZeroClipboard.config({ swfPath:     "/Content/ZeroClipboard.swf" });

                        var client = new ZeroClipboard($(".copy-button"));
                        client.on('copy', function (event) {
                            event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', event.target.innerText);
                        });

                        client.on("aftercopy", function (event) {

                            $("#alerta button").after('<span>Matricula copiada</span>');
                            $('#alerta').fadeIn('slow');
                            $('#alerta').setTimeout(close(), 3000);
                             });
                    </script>
```

and I have `div` on body :

```
  <div class="alert alert-info" id="alerta" style="display: none; ">
     <button type="button" class="close"></button>
         </div>
```

but my `setTimeout` doesn't work. What can I do?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you have trouble with? And why clipboard part is important to your question?

Comment: my "alert" statement have worse view, and it's not temporal, if I clic it, just stay if I no close it or press "ok" button, so I want the message close automatically after '5' seconds, clipboard is important because I clarify that message appear when I clic to the copy action.

Comment: I still can't get why clipboard part is important... I guess it makes otherwise trivial task of showing static HTML element with `jQuery.show` (or equivalent) into some interesting and non-trivial task... Consider updating your post to clarify, also showing what you already tried to replace `alert` would be nice too.

Comment: Just include a hidden `<div>` element in your view, the update its contents and display it, then use a javascript timer event to hide it after a certain time. [Refer this fiddle for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/kgjxkrx4/1/)

Comment: my div is hidden, (display : none)  hide it, I think my problem is more with javascript because timer event dont works correctly  (it no close automatically div)

Comment: @GerardoQuintana, Look at the fiddle I created for you in my last comment

Comment: your example are awesome!, but it no works for me because I don't have button, I have class called copy-button like this:  <td class="copy-button"> and my table field is my button

Comment: I only did that as an example because I could not use your code. You just need to put it in you `client.on()` function. If your having trouble, I can post an answer.

Comment: I did it .. show my answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

Setimeout should be written as follows

```
$('#alerta').setTimeout(close, 3000);
```

No Parenthesis.

Comment: Explanation: with parentheses the `close()` function is called immediately and the timeout works (and probably fails) on the returned result of that function call. Without parentheses a *reference* to the function is passed, to be called at the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

There is body div

```
<div class="alert alert-info" id="alert" style="display: none; ">
    <button type="button" class="alertaderecha">La matrícula ha sido    copiada.</button>
```

and there is javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ZeroClipboard.config({ swfPath: "/Content/ZeroClipboard.swf"});

    var client = new ZeroClipboard($(".copy-button"));

    client.on('copy', function (event) {
        event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', event.target.innerText);
    });

    client.on("aftercopy", function (event) {
        var message = $("#alert").after('');
        $('#alert').fadeIn('slow');
        var time = setTimeout(function (e) {
            message.hide();
        }, 3000);
    });
</script>
```

any answer ask here

SPECIAL THANKS TO @  Stephen Muecke

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ahh, my mistake, will remove my comment. Thanks for the pointer!